# Strange bug with python REPL in Mac Terminal - not exiting properly, not behaving properly

Tags: python, macos, bash, macports

I have multiple versions of python installed on my mac. The default python /usr/bin/python runs without any strange behaviour. However, running any of several python distros (2.6,2.7,3.5) installed using macports has the following strange behaviour.
I type:

```
>>> 1+1
```

and hit enter. Instead of printing 2 and then printing `>>>` on a new line it prints

```
>>> 2
```

and the cursor moves to the next line.

If I type:

```
>>> exit()
```

it exits, but incorrectly. The bash prompt is there but if I type a command my input does not appear. The output of commands I type does appear. If I just hit enter it reprints the prompt but without adding a newline.

To stop this I can run python which loads the REPL again, type `exit()` which finally returns me to the usual bash terminal behaviour.

I have screengrabs but not enough reputation to post images.

I have no idea what could be causing this as I have used this version of python for months without problems, and the fact that it is across python distros suggests it may be on the bash level - but in that case why does it not effect the default mac install of python.

I am extremely confused and would be grateful for any help or even just ideas of things to google for!

Comment: Does using `stty sane` on bash correct the issue?

Comment: Just a blind try use ctrl+D instead of exit() and see still the issue persists. :)

Comment: @cdarke yes, that does indeed fix the prompt. I have never seen that command before. Does this imply something about the cause??

Comment: 3 questions that may help me help you: 1)what is your terminal type to?  `echo $TERM`, 2) are you using mac osx terminal or say iterm, 3) if you change to a different shell type say `tcsh` is the problem reproducible?. The first question and the second will help root out the terminal being the source of the issue, the third would rule out bash you have already ruled out python so we can get to the bottom of this. also if you can execute commands what happens when you `clear` the terminal do you get your prompt back?

Comment: @Ajay Thanks for the help. 1) `echo $TERM` returns: xterm-256color. 2) I am using mac osx terminal. 3) tcsh reproduces the problem inside the repl, i.e.it prints newlines and output in the wrong order or something. However, `>>>exit()` seems to do the correct thing now, although it does print one last `>>>` before it exits. 4) `clear` does not fix the problem. It displays the prompt but still not my input. Thanks again

Comment: Well if it just sorted itself out then great, but if you were able to figure out what the problem was, and how it was fixed then go ahead an answer your own question